# Pandas: Merge two data frames and keep non-intersecting data from a single data frame

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, data-ingestion

Desire:

I want a way to merge two data frames and keep the non-intersected data from a specified data frame.

Problem:

I have duplicate data and I expected this line to remove that duplicate data:

```
 final_df = new_df[~new_df.isin(previous_df)].dropna()
```

Example  data and data test:

```
 record = Record(1000, 9300815, '<redacted type>', '<redacted id>')
 test_df = pd.DataFrame([record])
 if not final_df.empty:

      # this produces an empty data frame
      empty_df = test_df[test_df.isin(final_df)].dropna()

      # this produces the record
      record_df = final_pdf[final_pdf.col01 == record.col01]
```

Background:

I'm loading xml data and converting the xml file into several different record types as namedtuples.  I split each record type into its own dataframe.  I then compare the current set of data from the xml file with the data already loaded into the database by constructing `previous_df` as such:

```
 previous_df = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, con=conn, schema=schema, columns=columns)
```

Columns are dynamically created based on the fields in the named tuple.  The database schema is generated using sqlalchemy, and I have added `UniqueConstraint` to manage when I think there are duplicates within the database.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Look at [pandas.DataFrame.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas-dataframe-duplicated).  if you add some sample data and expected output, you get some detailed help.

Comment: I've also used `drop_duplicates(keep=False)`, which effectively calls `duplicated` and then removes them in a single line.    I really need a good way to merge two data frames and remove their intersection.

Comment: I would recommand to see [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) about merging dataframes. I don't see exactly where you want to go, but you can find a solution to your problem there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PRESERVING SINGLE RECORDS FROM BOTH DATAFRAMES:**

Try to `concat` the dataframes first, so you are sure that you will have duplicates. Then apply `drop_duplicates` and I think you will end up with what you are after. See the example below:

```
#Create dummy data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B"],data=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
print(df1)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B"],data=[[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
print(df2)

   A   B
0  3   4
1  5   6
2  7   8
3  9  10

#Concatenate dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
print(df)

   A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
0  3   4
1  5   6
2  7   8
3  9  10

#Drop duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df)

   A   B
0  1   2
2  7   8
3  9  10
```

**PRESERVING SINGLE RECORDS FROM ONE DATAFRAME ONLY:**

If you only want to keep the data from the new dataframe, just use a dirty little trick: `concat` the old dataframe twice, so all old records will fall under drop_duplicates criteria. Like so:

```
#Concatenate dataframes with old dataframe taken twice!
df = pd.concat([df1,df1,df2],axis=0)

#Now you will only end up with the records from second dataframe
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df)

   A   B
2  7   8
3  9  10
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that

Comment: If you only want to keep the data from the new dataframe, just use a dirty little trick: Concat the old dataframe twice, so all old records will fall under drop_duplicates criteria.

Comment: Works great!  Thanks!  +1 for your answer

Comment: Your little trick to preserve records from one dataframe only is just crazy and efficient, thank you so much !